# "Person or Group" picker showing users outside the SharePoint gorup

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-experience, people-picker, person-or-group

I have created a list and have added a Column of the type "Person or Group".
I have limited this field to just look into a SharePoint group to get an option

[image: options]

When I go and add an item the People Picker shows users who are not in the SharePoint group defined. If I select them validation kicks in which is good.

> Your organization's policies don't allow you to share with these users. Go to External Sharing in the Office 365 admin center to enable it.

Is there a way I can stop these other users from appearing in the People Picker?

Answer (score 2):

This is a default behavior in SharePoint online modern experience list forms.

I don't think there is any setting to avoid this behavior at the moment.

However, this works as expected in "classic experience". But I don't think moving again to the classic experience just because of this issue is good choice.